# Changing the default value of an instance variable

Tags: c#, object, instance-variables

Suppose I have these codes (and the classes are in the same namespace):

```
 class Animal
 {
    int numberOfLegs = 4; // initialized
    public int returnNumberOfLegs()
    {
      return numberOfLegs;
    }
 }

class Snake
{
   internal Animal myAnimalObject = new Animal();
   myAnimalObject.numberOfLegs = 0; // why is this line not allowed? 
}

class Program
{
   public static void Main(string [] args)
   {
      Snake mySnakeObject = new Snake();
      Console.WriteLine("Snake");
      Console.WriteLine("Number of Legs: {0}", mySnakeObject.myAnimalObject.returnNumberOfLegs());
   }
}
```

Observe the class Snake. When I place these 2 lines of code in Main(), it is possible/allowed and will work if I declare the variable numberOfLegs with the right access modifier. Why can't I do it in the class Snake itself? What should I do to allow it?

Note that the 2nd line of code from class Snake is invalid and these are the errors it produced:
1) Error    1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
2) Error    2   'myNamespaceName.Snake.myAnimalObject' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Thanks. I just want to learn about this.

Edit:
Okay, thanks guys. I know about constructors and inheritance, but somehow, I'm being forced to do it "the hard and not-so-smart" way, for learning purposes(?). And that I even had to set the default value to 4. Thank you for your replies. Plus, I just made up these classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because executable code should be placed either in constructor or in some method/property.
You cannot place code just inside the class, put it in the constructor.

```
    class Snake
    {
        internal Animal myAnimalObject = new Animal();
        public Snake()
        {
              myAnimalObject.numberOfLegs = 0;
        }
    }
```

When you write

```
    internal Animal myAnimalObject = new Animal();
```

in the class body, it's a kind of a syntax sugar; compiler will create constructor and put your code line inside it.
and it will look like

```
    class Snake
    {
        internal Animal myAnimalObject;
        public Snake()
        {
              myAnimalObject = new Animal();
              myAnimalObject.numberOfLegs = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't do this in the class initializer:

```
myAnimalObject.numberOfLegs = 0;
```

Since you're not setting a class member itself, but rather interacting with a class member, you'd have to do it in the constructor:

```
public Snake()
{
    myAnimalObject.numberOfLegs = 0;
}
```

Also, in order to access `numberOfLegs` it would need to be `internal` or `public`:

```
internal int numberOfLegs = 4; // initialized
```

More to the point of the whole scenario however, this seems like a very odd abstraction.  Though part of me applauds the use of composition instead of inheritance, this seems more like a case where inheritance is warranted.  It seems that `Animal` really shouldn't be initializing any value for `numberOfLegs` by default.  Indeed, `Animal` shouldn't even be a concrete object given the real-world concepts being modeled.  Instead, I might try something like:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int NumberOfLegs { get; }
}

class Snake : Animal
{
    public override int NumberOfLegs { get { return 0; } }
}
```

The idea being that a `Snake` *is* an `Animal`, that an `Animal` by itself can't exist unless it's a specific *type* of `Animal`, and that each individual type of `Animal` internally controls its own values and all the abstract `Animal` class does is define what those values need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inheritance instead. Make Animal an abstract class, base class for all animals. Composition (what you use now) does not make much sense in this case.

```
abstract class Animal
{
    protected int numberOfLegs = 4; // default number of legs
    public int NumberOfLegs { get { return numberOfLegs; } }

    public Animal(int legs)
    {
        numberOfLegs = legs; // initialize number of legs
    }
}
```

All concrete animals then derive from this class.

```
class Snake : Animal
{   
   public Snake() : base(0) // specify that number of legs is 0
   {

   }
}
```

The `base(0)` is a call to a base class constructor, so you are calling `Animal(int legs)` with an argument 0.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    private readonly int numberOfLegs; 

    protected Animal(int nrLegs = 4)
    {
       numberOfLegs = nrLegs;
    }
    public int returnNumberOfLegs()
    {
      return numberOfLegs;
    }
}

class Snake : Animal
{
   public Snake() : base(0)
   {
   }
}
```